# How to create animation in Flash by codes?

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I want to create animation in Flash by codes because I felt difficult when create them by accessing on graphic and making frames. It there a way to create professional animation by programming it?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Try and be more **specific** about the animation... Are you talking about sliding or fading etc? Or you mean full character animation (ie: side-view of walking, jumping etc)? That's why it's important to show what you've tried so far, so we understand easier...

Comment: Use an `enterFrame` function to make things move over time. Look up **AS3 using enterframe for animation**. Try looking for **AS3 bouncing ball tutorial** since those are usually a simpler for introduction to enter-frame concepts.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to crate animation in AS3

1. simplest way is to create with enterFrame.

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);

```
private function onEnter(e:Event):void
{
    //Do the Animation stuff here   
    object.x++;
}
```

2. you can use animation library to create nice animation.
   I use greensock( https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as ).